# Azure VM : Add New Property Item to Registry via ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I create Azure VM (windows) via arm template from Azure Pipeline. But I have to Add New Property Item to Registry without RDP.

Is there a secure way to do that with ARM template or SDK?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Best

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with many different ways. One method is to perform an ARM deployment and use `commandToExecute` inside it. You could also perform that using a Powershell task without having to login in the VM through Azure portal using az cli.

An example can be found below:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: execute command inside vm
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'subscription'
        scriptType: 'ps'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: 'az vm run-command invoke --command-id RunPowerShellScript --name $(vm_name) -g $(vnet_rg_name) --scripts "hostname"'
```

In the scripts section instead of the `hostname` you should add a powershell to edit your registry key.

Documented article:
https://medium.com/@geralexgr/execute-powershell-command-without-username-password-on-azure-virtual-machine-8142ade31fd0

Comment: thanks for response. But we are not allowed to using inline script or powershell commands. I create a python script using sdk for run-command but I'm not sure that it is the secure way.